# Json_encode in php and retrieve it in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am new to Jquery, Hence i am posting this question, may be its simple .

I have written the query in php page and i want to retrive it it jquery page .The php page is as follows.

```
   $chkuser = "SELECT A.* FROM mcd_users A WHERE A.User_Handle=('{$User_Handle}') 
   AND A.User_Password=('{$User_Password}')  AND A.Rec_Status='A' AND      
   A.User_Status='A'";

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($chkuser);  
        //$stmt->bindParam("id", $_GET[id]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $login = $stmt->fetchObject();
        $dbh = null;

        echo '{"item":'. json_encode($login) .'}';
```

JQuery Code :-

```
      $.ajax({
                        url: 'ajax_files/login.php',
                   crossDomain: true,
                            type: 'post',
                        data: $("#loginForm").serialize(), 
                       success: function(data){
                        if(data!== null)
                        {alert(data);
                            //var res=$json.decode(data);
                            //alert(res);                           
                        }

                    }
        }); // Ajax Call
```

Now when i **alert(data);** it shows.

```
  {"item": 
{"User_Id":"1110","Rec_Status":"A","Rec_Seq":"3","UserApplication_Id":"101",
"User_Type":"U","
User_Handle":"MCD_Admin","User_Password":"827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b",
"PasswordChanged_Date":"2014-08-04",
"User_Status":"A","User_Email":"gasian@muj.com","User_Phone":"8877665544",
"Locked":"N","Reset":"N","Customer_Id":"10","CreatedBy":"1110",
"CreatedOn":"2013-07-30  00:00:00","ModifiedBy":"1110","ModifiedTime":"2014-08-04 10:49:20"}}   **
```

Now i need to display only the User_Handle which is MCD_Admin in jquery.js page.How to retrieve it.Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need it to say `item`. Since you know that, why not `echo json_encode($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));`. It will be an Object when it gets evaluated by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
alert(data.item.User_Handle)
```

EDIT

If above code not works try this

```
var result = JSON.parse(data);
alert(result.item.User_Handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jquery.parsejson
```

is your friend here you can read more about it here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

example code on how to use it

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Comment: its showing [object Object] when i tried the above syntax

Comment: jquery.parsejson returns a js object from a json string. so after parsing you will get a js object.  dont alert it check it in console using console.log(jquery.parsejson(data)); you will get to see the result. for more detail follow the parse link as specified in answer

Answer (score 0):

jquery's `parseJSON` would work.

```
var a=$.parseJSON('{"item": {"User_Id":"1110","Rec_Status":"A","Rec_Seq":"3","UserApplication_Id":"101","User_Type":"U"," User_Handle":"MCD_Admin","User_Password":"827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b","PasswordChanged_Date":"2014-08- 04","User_Status":"A","User_Email":"gasian@muj.com","User_Phone":"8877665544","Locked":"N","Reset":"N","Customer_Id":"10","CreatedBy":"1110","CreatedOn":"2013-07-30 00:00:00","ModifiedBy":"1110","ModifiedTime":"2014-08-04 10:49:20"}}');

alert(a.item.User_Handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert(json.item.User_Handle);
       }
```

Comment: @Shreyas TG try this,may this 'll help you :)

Answer (score 0):

set data type json in ajax request as:-

```
     $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_files/login.php',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: $("#loginForm").serialize(), 
        success: function(data){
            if(data!== null)
            {
                alert(data.item.User_Handle);                      
            }
        }
  });
```

and get User_Handle  as:- alert(data.item.User_Handle)